# Alterar cor de um campo da tabela html segundo condição do status do banco php

Tags: php, mysql

Em uma tabela gerada à partir de dados de um banco de dados, preciso alterar para determinadas cores de um `<td></td>` se o valor do campo lido no banco de dados estiver como: 0 ou 1. Exemplo se o campo lido estiver em 0 o background `<td></td>` fica vermelho, se tiver 1 fica azul.

Meu código está assim:

```
require_once('class/Conexao.class.php');
                 $cnpj = $_SESSION['CNPJ'];
                    try {
                        $pdo = new Conexao(); 
                        $resultado = $pdo->select("SELECT protocolo,nomeBoleto,categoria,hr_dt_inserido,lido FROM boletos WHERE CNPJ='$cnpj' ORDER BY hr_dt_inserido DESC");
                        $pdo->desconectar();

                        }catch (PDOException $e){
                            echo $e->getMessage();
                        }   
                        //resgata os dados na tabela
                        if(count($resultado)){
                            foreach ($resultado as $res) {
    $msg .="                <tr>";
    $msg .="                    <td>".$res['protocolo']."</td>";
    $msg .="                    <td>".$res['nomeBoleto']."</td>";
    $msg .="                    <td>".$res['categoria']."</td>";
    $msg .="                    <th>".date('d/m/Y', strtotime($res["hr_dt_inserido"]))."</th>";
    $msg .= '               <td><a href="visualizar.php?protocolo=' . $res['protocolo'] . '" class="btn btn-primary" target="_blank">Visualizar</a></td>';
    $msg .= '               <td><a href="download.php?protocolo='. $res['protocolo'].'" class="btn btn-primary">Download</a></td>';
    $msg .="                </tr>";                            
                            }   
                        }else{
                            $msg = "";
                            $msg .="Nenhum resultado foi encontrado...";
                        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode adicionar uma classe na `td` terminando com o valor 0 ou 1. Por exemplo:

```
"<td class='fundo". $res['campo que retorna 0 ou 1'] ."'>".$res['protocolo']."</td>";
```

E no CSS você cria o estilo das duas classes, `.fundo0` e `.fundo1`:

```
<style>
.fundo0{
   background-color: red; /* fundo vermelho */
}

.fundo1{
   background-color: blue; /* fundo azul */
}
</style>
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, mto obrigado!